# What version of keras is required to use preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array function?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

After finding [this page](https://keras.io/api/preprocessing/timeseries/) in the keras documentation, I decided that the `timeseries_dataset_from_array` function would suit what I was trying to do. But when trying to import it using

`from keras.preprocessing import timeseries_dataset_from_array`

or `from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import timeseries_dataset_from_array`

I get the following message: `ImportError: cannot import name 'timeseries_dataset_from_array' from 'keras.preprocessing'`

[Here it is](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/preprocessing/timeseries.py) in the tensorflow source code. This is on Tensorflow 2.3, but have also tried 2.1 and 2.2. Keras is 2.4.3

How can I import the function?

Comment: make sure you're using the associated/correct version of tensorflow.keras

Comment: I've edited and posted versions. Not sure what the version requirement is for this function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation of Tensorflow it is in the `nightly` build currently.
You can check the example that uses this API [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/time_series).

You can install the nightly build by the following command.

```
pip install -q tf-nightly
```

Ideally, it is supposed to be in `v2.3.0` as per the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/timeseries_dataset_from_array). But as you have mentioned that you have already tried using `2.3.0`, I will suggest to install the nightly build and check it out.